# SharePoint 2010 how to customize display form using application page or code behind

Tags: development, custom, application-pages, display-form

I am working on a project that requires code behind in the dispform.aspx as well as the edit and new form.  The reson being, I am synching to a web service, on view of an item, I want to make a sall to the web service to get updated data on the record in SharePoint.

I've looked a list definitions, using delegate controls (I was able to link delegate control but unable to find controls in the display form, seems they are in a table without ids etc)

I have created an application page in an empty SharePoint project in Visual Studio 2010, added a listviewwebpart (rather use instead of dataview because the lookup values are displayed as hyperlinks).  This page resides in the _Layouts folder.

The question is, how do I add code behind to the OOB dispform.aspx page without having to use list definitions, etc.  If I can use the form I created in the layouts folder, can I use this for my list display?  (SharePoint 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered, one way is to use the DelegateControl approach (with PlaceholderAdditionalPagehead) and that's in fact what I've been using for a couple of years now.

The key is how to access the built-in editform.aspx/dispform.aspx pages with the embedded WebPart showing the SPListItem. That's done by hooking your WebControl into OnPreRender/OnLoad to check `SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode` if you are on a SharePoint form page.

Then you need to find the ListFormWebPart and get your hands on the fields you are looking for.

Basically something like the pseudo-code below (though it is much simplified for brevity):

First, get the ASP.NET controls of the current page:

```
this.Page.Controls
```

Then find the ListFormWebPart (either loop recursively or use another smart way to find it deep down the controls collection):

```
if (typeof(ListFormWebPart) == childControl.GetType())
ListFormWebPart listFormWebPart = (ListFormWebPart)childControl;
```

Finally, dive into the controls collection of the ListFormWebPart to find the `ListFieldIterator` control (again, either loop recursively or use another smart way to find it deep down the controls collection) which itself contains a collection of the actual fields of the SPListItem. E.g. for a text field:

```
if (typeof(TextField) == formFieldChild.GetType())
{
  TextField textField = (TextField)formFieldChild;
  if (textField.FieldName == "YourFieldNameGoesHere")
  {
    // Get the field value and do with it whatever you want
    string myFieldValue = textField.Text;
  }
}
```

Another way would be to use client-side JavaScript and the CSOM to pull data from the selected item (e.g. by getting the SPListItem ID from the Url of Dispform.aspx and query the SharePoint Webservice via REST/SOAP) and push it via XmlHttpRequest to your custom WebService.

Finally, the last thing that comes into my mind is to develop a custom ControlAdapter to hook into the ListFormWebPart and read its fields etc., though I haven't tried this myself because I'm quite happy with the DelegateControl approach mentioned above.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** Added a few lines to clarify things a little bit more.

Comment: thanks, wonderful treasure hunt down in the template containers, but was able to find it, make the seb service call and update the listitem. DelegateControl is a great means to do this, I just needed to recursively go through the controls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities for getting custom code on a list page:

- Web Parts: You can create a custom web part that you add to the page (you can add web parts through the Web interface like any other web part page.
- AdditionalPageHead delegate control:  The AdditionalPageHead delegate runs on every SharePoint page and you can use that to get your own code on the page.  Here is a post I wrote about that a while back: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/

**EDIT**

You could also use InfoPath.  In SharePoint 2010 you can customize the list form to use InfoPath for new/edit/display forms.  And in the InfoPath form, you can use code behind or the built-in functionality of InfoPath to call your web services.